# Angular Bootstrap table Slowing While Displaying Data

Tags: javascript, ajax, json, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

i am using simple bootstrap table in angular.
my problem is that the data is fetched using AJAX from other server.

So in this case i have made a globalCtrl and calling AJAX as soon app in Initialized. using angular.bootstrap(document,"myApp")  in my case.

The table length runs into 6000 strong as an JSON Array and its taking a lot of time to display. 
secondly while using navigation the page slows down since this AJAX gets called again.

```
app.controller("globalCtrl",function($scope,$rootScope,$http)
{

$rootScope.showTable=false;
//get JSON DATA FROM SERVER  
$http.get(RESTURL.getSentiments).then(function(res)
          {
                log(res);
                $rootScope.sentimentDispData = res.data;
                $rootScope.showTable=true;
          }); /*AJAX ENDS*/





});
```

HTML markup

```
<div class="col-1g-12">
<h1 ng-show="!showTable">Please Wait Table Data is Loading.....</h1>
<table class="table" ng-show="showTable">
<thead>
<tr>
<th>Anger</th>
<th>Disgust</th>
<th>Fear</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
  <tr  ng-repeat="sent in sentimentDispData | orderBy:sortType:sortReverse">
<td>{{sent.Anger}}</td>
<td>{{sent.Disgust}}</td>
<td>{{sent.Fear}}</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>

</div>
```

For landing Page there is landingCtrl
Above code is in globalCtrl

Comment: 6000 anything in HTML built with JS won't work. Either use pagination or try a virtualized list solution (https://github.com/stackfull/angular-virtual-scroll)